# Django - redirect to login page if UserProfile matching query does not exist error

Tags: django, django-users

I have extended the user model using the `UserProfile` method. However I occasionally get the Django error message `UserProfile matching query does not exist` when running the query `request.user.get_profile()`

I think this is happening when I have become logged out of the system so my user becomes an `AnonymousUser`. Is there any way I can automatically redirect the user back to the login page if a `UserProfile` does not exist.

I am using `request.user.get_profile()` in quite a few places so don't really want to go through my code putting checks on everyone so was thinking of a way using signals or something similar where I only have to do it once.

Also I am using `@login_required` on my function calls but this doesn't seem to be redirecting the user before they get this error.

Every registered user should have a UserProfile account as this is automatically created if they don't have one when they log into the system.

I am also using Django 1.1

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
def profile_required():
    def has_profile(user):
        try:
            user.get_profile()
        except:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    return user_passes_test(lambda u: has_profile(u))
```

Answer (score 0):

> so was thinking of a way using signals or something similar where I only have to do it once.

AFAIK you cannot do this with a signal.

You can however create a custom decorator to replace `login_required`. This decorator can wrap `login_required` and check for user profile. You can then replace Django's `login_required` with your own in the import statement.

Comment: I'm not familiar with custom decorators.  Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `@login_required` decorator ensures that the user is logged in. This error is probably occurring because some user records don't have a UserProfile. You can test this in the shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import *
for u in User.objects.all():
    try:
        u.get_profile()
    except:
        print "%s does not have a profile" % u
```